# How can I add permanent data into an variable

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project that plays a game of rock paper scissors
the game works fine but i want to add something into it. a pointing system where it will add 1 each time a player win but i can't seem to make this work i've been trying to find workarounds for almost 2 day now but i can't seem to find any solution. The thing is the code works but after i log the function that adds 1 to a variable but after that it returns to it's original value which is 0.

```
const one = 1
function addone(test){
    test += 1
}
addone(one)
console.log(one)
```

This print the original value like the function did not do anything to it. im so confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems in your code:

- `one` is a `const` variable. That means that you can't modify its initial value.
- `test` is a local variable inside your function, that means function won't modify the values of the variable that you pass as parameter (`one`).

There is an operator(`++`) that add a unit, I highly recommend you to use it instead of make a function:

```
var one = 1

one++;
console.log(one)
```

If you want to use a function you have to do like this:

```
var one = 1

function addone(test){
    return test+1;
}

one = addone(one);
console.log(one)
```

In terms to store permanent data into a javascript variable, that's not possible. Variable are stored in RAM, that means that when you stop the program, al data of your program are wiped. Permanent store are made in database and other complex data structures.

If you want to play multiple games, you should consider to allow the players to play more games before the program finish.

Comment: The function won't modify the value of the argument because Javascript passes primitives by value instead of reference.

Comment: As @BrunoLipovac comment Javascript passes primitives by value. I've made a low-level explanation to provide an easily understand.

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much i never think that i could get more dumb so i cant manipulate it because it's just a copy of that variable that im inputing as parameter? so it means that the function did not touch the variable at all. I wish i could go back to my mother's womb.

and the const it's just a typo very sorry for this.
i did not know this website is very active i thought i would wait days just to get a response thank you very much and have a nice day

Comment: Your welcome!. Mozilla has a lot articles where they explained fundamental things about javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript.